# Finding the Jordan Decomposition of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Given $$ \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$am
I need to find a Jordan Decomposition of this matrix. For this purpose I am trying to follow the following  theorem:

Theorem **1**

**If $N \in L(V)$ is nilpotent, then there exist vectors $v_1$,$v_2$,...$v_k$ $\in V$ such that**

(i)**$\{v_1,Nv_1,..N^{m(v_1)}v_1,...,v_k,Nv_k,....,N^{m(v_k)}v_k\}$ is a basis of $V$**

(ii) **$\{N^{m(v_1)}v_1,....,N^{m(v_k)}v_k\}$ is a basis of null $N$**.

Then I am trying to find generalized eigenspaces corresponding to the eigen values $1$(say $U_1$) and $2$ (say $U_2$). My calculations show that $$U_1=span\{(1,0,0)^t,(0,1,0)^t\}$$ and $$U_2=span\{(0,0,1)^t\}$$

Then $(T-\lambda_i)|_{U_i}$ is nilpotent for $i=1,2$.-Then I want to use Theorem $1$ to conclude. But I am going wrong somewhere.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Your matrix is in Jordan form .

Comment: I should get the same martrix as well when I try to find the decomposition then

Comment: Obviously! See my answer.

Comment: you don't recognize that your  matrix is in jordan canonical form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your job is correct but useless because the result is trivial and immediate from the start. The matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

**is in Jordan form** and we see immediately that it has eigenvalues $2$ and $1$ with algebraic multiplicity $2$
so you have:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The generlized eigenvectors are the columns of the identity matrix.

Comment: I have a few questions. I got the identity matrix. Why are you multiplying it with the given matrix?? Do I need to do the same always??

Comment: The Jordan decomposition of a matrix $A$ is $A=SJS^{-1}$ where $S$ is a matrix that has as columns the (generalized) eigenvalue. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.....